# how to show different data when hover menu in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have category with unlimited subcategories in my project.

I'm using return method ( with id and parent_id ) to show categories in my menu.

This is my `CategoryController` to show categories :

```
$categories = Category::where('parent_id', 0)->get();
```

This is my blade to show categories in menu :

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
     <li class="list-item list-item-has-children mega-menu mega-menu-col-5">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">{{ $category->name }}</a>
              @include('layouts.categories-group',['categories' => $categories])
     </li>
@endforeach
```

As you can see i include a new file with this contents :

```
<ul class="sub-menu nav">
     @foreach($categories as $category)
         <li class="list-item list-item-has-children">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#">{{ $category->name }}</a>
             @if($category->child->count())
                 @include('layouts.categories-group',['categories' => $category->child])
             @endif
         </li>
     @endforeach
</ul>
```

These codes working well for me, but here is a problem, when i hover first item of menu i will see all of the categories, but i want to show categories who regarding to same category with parent_id -> 0

You can see this in images :

*When i hover first item of menu*
[image: First item]
*When i hover second item of menu*
[image: Second item]
*When i hover third item of menu*
[image: Third item]

As you can see, in all of the items in menu i see all of the categories.

EDIT :

This is complete menu codes :

```
<nav class="main-menu">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="list float-right">

            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <li class="list-item list-item-has-children mega-menu mega-menu-col-5">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">{{ $category->name }}</a>
                    @include('layouts.categories-group',['categories' => $categories])
                </li>
            @endforeach

            <li class="list-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('contact.contact') }}">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('about.about') }}">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Where's the code related to hovering and content hide/show? Your php code isn't really as relevant here as the html, css and js

Comment: First foreach with <li></li> tags is my menu, this menu using bootstrap classes

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering all categories also in sub-view. Maybe you can insert to sub-view only one parent category, and there you should call

```
Foreach($category->child as $child_category)
```

And render children of parent category

Comment: But i think i have to use jquery or javascript to handle this problem, isn't that so?